# Create JSON object from string of locations

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I have a list of locations returned from a mapping service in the following format.

```
   [115.772933,-32.095437], [115.772933,-32.095437], 
   [115.772933,-32.095437],
```

I need to insert this into a mongoDB collection as a valid JSON object but I am not sure how to embed a string into a valid JSON object in javascript. I have tried JSONparse but I am getting errors.

```
var coordinates = "[115.772933,-32.095437], [115.772933,-32.095437], [115.772933,-32.095437],"

        var polygons = {
    "type" : "Polygon",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        [ 
  coordinates
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
"use strict";

let coordinates =  [[115.772933,-32.095437], [115.772933,-32.095437], [115.772933,-32.095437]];
let polygons = {
    'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': coordinates
};

let jsonData = JSON.stringify(polygons);

console.log(jsonData);
```